# Character encoding error in Php

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding

Hi I am storing some text in a mysql column. The error I am getting is whenever there is an apostrophe (') in the text it's getting displayed as 'â€™'even though apostrophe is being displayed in the database Any ideas what would be the error? I have spent days but no luck

You can check the error here : http://beta.writiely.com/

Here how it's connecting and fetching result

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from textDocs";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$res = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
array_push($res,array('t'=>$row['t'],'co'=>$row['cover'],
     'text'=>$row['txt']));
    }
} else {
    return false;
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: What is the charset of your MySQL table vs your page? Seems to me like you must have a difference there. It would be best to keep everything in utf-8 if you can.

Comment: it's utf8_general_ci, that's the first thing I checked I even tried changing it to to utf8_bin but no luck

Comment: Show how you query this database, and what is the database encoded as? (charset != collation)

Comment: @Qirel - that's right, the charset. My mistake. I updated my comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: charset is utf8 and I am using the normal select * query

Comment: My point was just that even if the collation is set to say `utf8_general_ci`, it's not necessarily that the charset is utf8 as well.

Comment: @user3772366 How did you check that the charset is utf8? Did you just look at the collation-field? Also, what I ment by *Show how you query this database* is the code for that query in PHP - the connection included.

Comment: Besides charset issue, you have an issue with html entities. If you save html  in db using htmlentities, then you have to output result without using htmlentities again (there is a lot of `&nbsp;`  in your page).

Comment: @Qirel I ahve updated my question with the code

Comment: @fusion3k how can i output with keeping the html tags?

Comment: Try adding `$conn->set_charset("utf8");` right after creating the connection, specifying the charset there. As for the reverse function of `htmlentities()`, that's `html_entity_decode()`.

Comment: @Qirel tried that :(. Even tried 'utf8mb4' as another answer suggested doesn't seem to work...the mysql version is 5.5.45 and my server charset is UTF 8 Unicode

Answer (score 1):

`â€™` is the Mojibake for the utf8 `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK`, which is not normally used in computer circles.  (You probably got it from some Word processing package.)

htmlentities should not be relevant to this discussion.  If the web page has `&acirc;&euro;&trade;`, you have a big mess.  I don't think it has `&rsquo;` based on what you have said.

Yes, `$conn->set_charset("utf8");` is needed.  And this is usually the fix for this type of problem.

However, you also need the table/column to be `CHARACTER SET utf8`, is it?  Do `SHOW CREATE TABLE` to check.

`utf8` and `utf8mb4` do not differ in this context.  The latter is needed for Emoji and some of Chinese.

The "collation" (such as `utf8_general_ci`) is not relevant to this discussion.  However, `utf8_general_ci` applies *only* to `utf8`, so some of the comments were unambiguous.

Summary:

- Your bytes are apparently utf8,
- Do the `set_charset`,
- Check the table/column,
- HTML4 needs `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">`; HTML5 can shorten it: `<meta charset="UTF-8">` (but apparently this is not the issue).

Comment: I got it to work thanks! For some reason <meta charset=UTF-8> wasn't working but using header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8') in php it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I added what might be the answer.